# bitwise operation for c confusion

Tags: c

> Assuming that x is a positive integer, the following function returns 1 if x is a certain type
> of values or it returns 0 otherwise.
>
> ```
> int mystery(int x) {
>     return !((x-1) & x);
> }
> ```
>
> What does mystery(20) return?

May I ask how do we approach this type of qn ?
My idea is to express x in binary and do bitwise operation with it.
Do correct me if I am wrong thanks !

Comment: This checks whether x is a power of two or not. It's just a common pattern that you're unlikely to get if you haven't seen it before.  The expression `(x - 1) & x` only produces 0 if x is zero, or x is a power of two (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32).

Comment: The reasoning behind that is: powers of two in binary only has 1 bit that's set to 1. when you subtract 1 from it, this bit will become zero for sure. Hence, the bitwise and of `x` and `x - 1` becomes zero.

Comment: Why not run the code to see what mystery(20) returns? I don't understand what the problem with evaluating it by hand is either. 20-1 is 19, 19&20 is 16 and !16 is 0.

Comment: @PaulHankin He is likely speaking on "what is returns in a logical sense", not evaluating specific inputs. I honestly don't see anything wrong with the question.

Comment: ohh i was wondering why !16 is equal to zero. Anything that is not !0 will give 0. Thanks

Comment: A hint at how to approach these questions: Do you know how `20` is represented on your computer? Do you know how `19` is represented on your computer? Do you know what the `&` operator does? If you can answer these three questions independently, you will be able to put together the answer.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Re “Why not run the code to see what mystery(20) returns?”: Because the question is not just what `mystery(20)` returns. The question is explicitly stated as “May I ask how do we approach this type of qn ?” (The first part of the question, all text up to and including “What does mystery(20) return?” appears to be quoted from a posed problem, presented for context for OP’s actual question, so it should have been marked as such.)

Comment: @Youssef13: Re “This checks whether x is a power of two or not”: Not quite.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work from the outside in.

```
!(expression)
```

you will get a 0 if expression is true, that is, not zero,
and you will get a 1 if expression is false, that is, zero.

So when will expression be non-zero, giving a zero as a result?  Whenever (x-1) has some bits in common with x.

What are examples?

- 0 - 1 = 0xfff... & 0, no bits in common, returns 1
- 1 - 1 = 0 & 1, no bits in common, returns 1
- 2 - 1 = 1 & 2, no bits in common, returns 1
- 3 - 1 = 2 & 3, bits in common, returns 0
- 4 - 1 = 3 & 4, no bits in common, returns 1
- 5 - 1 = 4 & 5, bits in common, returns 0
- 6 - 1 = 5 & 6, bits in common, returns 0
- 7 - 1 = 6 & 7, bits in common, returns 0
- 8 - 1 = 7 & 8, no bits in common, returns 1

It looks to me like we can say it returns 1 when the binary representation has exactly zero or one bits turned on in it.

0 or 1 or 10 or 100